# How to determiner a controller is available on the global namesapce in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope

In order to instantiate my controller with a mock scope object in the following unit test, I need to make sure that my controller is available on the global namesapce.

```
describe('testCtrl', function(){

  it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = new testCtrl(scope);

    expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

However, how to determine a controller is available on the global namesapce in angularJS ?

Comment: typeof testCtrl != undefined , actually controller is just a javascript function

Comment: Test seems to be very strange...

Comment: you will help documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example, the controller in the root module `app` should be on the global namespace, and the controller in the dependency module `products` should ne a non-Global controller.

`angular.module( 'app', [
  'products',
  ...
]);`

Comment: you can access "products " controller inside "app" module in entire application, but you have to declare "app" module top of application.